# I have two data frames df1 and df2, I need to filter out df1 using keys in df2 using start and end dates in df2, I need to get a result like df3

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter data using key from df2 with additional filter for start and end date, then df1 needs to be filtered using this criteria to get df3 (example output)

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = { 'KEY':  ['1747604', '1747604','2113901', '1747604','2113901', '2113901'],
       'date': ['2019-02-11', '2019-06-14', '2019-03-24', '2019-08-06', '2019-04-28' ,'2019-10-24'],
       'sales': [342, 234, 67, 564, 564 ,45]
      }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['KEY', 'date','sales'])

data2 = { 'KEY':  ['1747604', '2113901'],
       'strdate': ['2019-02-11', '2019-03-24'],
       'enddate': ['2019-07-06', '2019-09-26']
      }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['KEY', 'strdate','enddate'])
```

## I need an output as below df3 - using some kind of iter rows or lambda, sorry I could not find the answer anywhere.

```
df3
KEY date    sales
0   1747604 2019-02-11  342
1   1747604 2019-06-14  234
2   2113901 2019-03-24  67
3   2113901 2019-04-28  564
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first merge the `df1` and `df2` then filter rows where `date` is not between `strdate` and `enddate`.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
df3 = (df3[df3['date'].between(df3.strdate, df3.enddate)]
         .drop(columns = ['strdate', 'enddate']))
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
       KEY        date  sales
0  1747604  2019-02-11    342
1  1747604  2019-06-14    234
3  2113901  2019-03-24     67
4  2113901  2019-04-28    564
```

Comment: Fantastic! You are amazing Amit

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge the two dataframes. This gets rid of all rows for which the `KEY` is not in `df2`.

`df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='KEY', right_on='KEY')`

2. Filter out all rows for which the `date` is not between `strdate` and `enddate`.

`df3 = df3[(df3.date >= df3.strdate) & (df3.date <= df3.enddate)]`

3. Drop unnecessary columns that were only used for filtering.

`df3 = df3.drop(["strdate", "enddate"], axis=1)`